# Как в PhpStorm сделать по дефолту 1 таб у первого div после body

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Как в PhpStorm сделать так, чтобы после body автоматически ставился 1 таб.[image: Вот в данное место требуется поставить таб]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы добавить Tab после body, thead, tbody и т.д их нужно убрать из списка который отменяет эти Tab:

1. В своей IDE нажимаем Ctrl + Alt + S
2. Раскрываем полный список Code Style и выбираем HTML
3. Внутри HTML выбираем вкладку Other
4. Ищем надпись Do not indent children of: и убираем из списка исключений нужные нам теги. Готово.